# Session cookie prevents pages to load

Tags: cookies

There is a problem with Drupal 6 site. It seems seesion cookie is preventing some pages to load.

Site has approximately 5 to 10 pages (out of 30 000) of difference content types which can't be loaded. No errors returned — browser's wheel turning endlessly. After disabling cookies pages load just normally. After some testing I can say, that the problem in session cookie.

The problem doesn't exist in the development environment. I have made some testing on production (stopped Nginx and restarted Apache as single web-server) to make it similar to to development environment, but nothing changed. Now I have no idea how to debug the problem.

Thanks for any pointers.

[Solution]

The problem was in big sessions table (2GB). After truncating the table error has gone.

Comment: What errors related to these failed requests appear in server's error.log? I assume nothing in Drupal's watchdog, right? Does access.log show these connection at all, or are they dying at proxy / gateway / firewall and never hit your server at all?

Comment: Could you post how you Set your cookie? did you double check that you did it correctly. also are you testing with cookie extension on in your browser?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I solved the problem partially.

It was 504 error caused by session table, which was 2GB. I simply truncated the table.

I understand that this is not a good solution, but now I have time to understand it better.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add info about full session table to your question's body

Answer (score 0):

On large sites with many users and many simultaneous connections keeping sessions in database will cause a problems. So there are some tricks that may help you:

- Don't keep unneeded sessions for anonymous users. To do this, choose one of the following, from what I advise most, to what's easiest:

  - Upgrade to Drupal 7
  - Migrate to Pressflow
  - Use [No Anonymous Sessions](http://drupal.org/project/no_anon) module
- Move your sessions where they will do less damage:

  - [Memcache API and Integration](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) module allows sessions in memcached bin
  - [Memcache Storage](http://drupal.org/project/memcache_storage) (possibly with [Cache Backport](http://drupal.org/project/cache_backport)) offers the same functionality
  - Create your own session module looking at code of the above, for example to keep sessions in shared memory or in files on a ramdisc.
- Flush sessions every midnight (or other hour with no visitors)